# How to avoid Spring Data Jpa Concurrency situation?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, duplicates, spring-data

My project uses Spring Data JPA(`JpaRepository`) for persistence operations. However when multiple requests are executed simultaneously, data is getting duplicated in a table where I want to add only unique records.

This happens because at first time, for all threads there is no matching record in that table andbhence it allows all threads to save record in that table.

Any suggestions how I can avoid it.

I saw Locking and Isolation as some of the suggested ways but I am not sure how we can implement them if we use `JpaRepository` interface methods.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question. (add some code, configuration etc.).

Comment: Then you need a unique index in the table.

Comment: I have an unique index.. However even then it allows bcoz whole domain request is transactional type and it is distributed across multiple tables..                       And hence it is allowed for multiple threads.

Comment: Then your unique index isn't correct. If it is the same data and it shouldn't be allowed fix your database.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing Spring Data is causing. The means of control for that are in the JPA and database areas. I suggest you read up on optimistic locking with JPA as well as unique indexes in databases.